# Which DBMS should i choose for reordering query execution plan using Java?

Tags: java, nosql, bigdata, database

I am starting a Research project that involves evaluating the execution costs in each branch of the query execution plan and given a big data set the program would re write the query execution plan so that the query can be executed in certain time bounds.

I have experience with java and oracle but i have no prior experience with NoSql databases, I do have alot of options as of Pig, Casandara, CouchDB that i read initially.
My question(s) are as follows:

1. Can i reorder the query execution plan in oracle using JDBC?
2. What is the best option to do such kind of project (may be the most
   supportive DBMS)?

Answer (score 0):

The query execution plan is part of the DBMS Logic to execute you declarative SQL wishes.
When your throw you SQL queries against a SQL Server, there is a phase where your query gets "optimized" to run the underlying functions (which and when). SQL is just a way to let the DBMS know, what you want. 
What I understand from you question is, that you would like to have a tool to "pre"-optimize your query. Qracle and DB2 have some neat tools to do this, either in production, analyzing the incoming queries, or before, using tools provided by the vendor.

Because of SQL being a declarative wish thingy, you can optimize you queries, by minimizing the amount of data to be looked up. Use the `with` statement in Oracle to process only a portion or sub-query statements in DB2. Do not use sub-queries in MySQL. Avoid to many and statements in postgreSQL, use `in` instead.

Since the query execution plan is part of the DBMS you use, you have to buy your DBMS a drink first, before you can get all wild and optimized ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are things like Oracle Hints for NoSql queries. In addition (at least MongoDB) do not support joins, so there is much less space to optimize queries since they always act on a single collection.

What e.g. MongoDb supports is indexing of properties to optimize search queries based on them.  But whenever you need some kind of Joins you will fire two requests for it.

Maybe it's also worth to take a look on mongos [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) mechanism. Thats where you can handle aggregations on server side (still on single collections only). But even there I don't see much space to optimize queries before they get to the DB.

The [explain operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/) gives further information about debugging and optimizing mongoDB queries.

Some more about [optimizing MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/optimization/)